# How can I clear an external ID on a record in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite

I need to clear/reset the external ID on a record in NetSuite, but nothing I do is working.

Some of the InventoryItem records are incorrectly mapped to records in another system. I have an application that can sync up the two systems, but I need to clear NetSuite's external IDs first.

Responses don't really need to be SOAP-specific. If you know how to do it with some specific NetSuite/SuiteTalk client, that might point me in the right direction.

### What I've Tried

First up, I tried using the nullFieldList... but maybe it doesn't work because externalId is an attribute, not an element?

```
<messages:update>
    <messages:record internalId="7777" xsi:type="accounting:InventoryItem">
        <core:nullFieldList xsi:type="core:NullField">
            <core:name>externalId</core:name>
        </core:nullFieldList>
    </messages:record>
</messages:update>
```

The external ID is just a string, so I tried just setting it to blank. Didn't work either.

```
<messages:update>
    <messages:record internalId="7777" xsi:type="accounting:InventoryItem">
        <accounting:externalId></accounting:externalId>
    </messages:record>
</messages:update>
```

I even tried setting the external ID to 0, but I get back a "not unique identifier" error

```
<messages:update>
    <messages:record internalId="7777" xsi:type="accounting:InventoryItem">
        <accounting:externalId>0</accounting:externalId>
    </messages:record>
</messages:update>
```

### Other Info

I'm using NetSuite's SOAP API v.2013_1

When I say "it doesn't work", I mean: after I do the *update*, I get a *success* response similar to the following:

```
<readResponse>
    <platformCore:status isSuccess="true" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2013_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
    <record internalId="7777" externalId="42" xsi:type="listAcct:InventoryItem" xmlns:listAcct="urn:accounting_2013_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <!-- snip -->
    </record>
</readResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately my understanding is that once you set an externalid you cannot clear it, you can set it to another value, but not back to null.  I have experienced this both using SuiteScript as well as a Boomi process that uses the 2014.1 endpoint.  This may have changed in the recent releases, as I have not tried it recently with SuiteScript nor with a newer endpoint.

Comment: What I ended up doing is just setting the external IDs to the negative values (all the IDs I was using are positive integers), which has prevented any collisions. It's easily to automate and easy to check.

Comment: I used David's approach too. Set all negative, then re-imported again with the new IDs

Answer (score 3):

If you are using scripts in netsuite you can run a scheduled script to clear records in NS by loading each record and setting the externalid to '' using the following simple code:

```
var rec= nlapiLoadRecord(type,id);
rec.setFieldValue('externalid','');
nlapiSubmitRecord(rec);
```

This seemed to work for me in my enviornment which was on 2015.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the externalId on a record once it's been set. Here's an example using the [NetSuite gem](http://github.com/netsweet/netsuite):

```
ns_customer = NetSuite::Records::Customer.get external_id: 'ext_id'
ns_customer.external_id = ''
ns_customer.update
```

Here's the corresponding XML for `update`:

```
<env:Body>
  <platformMsgs:update>
    <platformMsgs:record xsi:type="listRel:Customer" platformMsgs:internalId="199113" platformMsgs:externalId=""/>
  </platformMsgs:update>
</env:Body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had to attempt this before as well. I know the pains you describe. I ended up putting a "-" in front of my external ID to unlink it between my systems. You can do this in SOAP or even as a simple one time csv upload. As it was one time, I did csv.